# An inequality involving box function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Let $t$ be an even integer greater than or equal to $6$ and $n$ is  an odd natural number. Then is it always true that :

$\lfloor\frac{5-t}{2} \rfloor+1 + \frac {t+n-3}{2} \geq 2$?

I have tried for many values of $t$ and $n=1$ and this is satisfied.

Any argument from anyone is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assume that $t$ is an even integer so $t=2k$.
Therefore, one has
\begin{align*}\lfloor\frac{5-t}{2} \rfloor+1 + \frac {t+n-3}{2}&= \lfloor\frac{5}{2} \rfloor-k+1+ \frac {t+n-3}{2}\\
&=3-k+k+\frac {n-3}{2}\\
&=\frac{n+3}{2}\\
&\geq \frac{1+3}{2}\\
&=2,
\end{align*}
because since $n$ is a natural odd number, $n\geq 1$. Remark that the inequality is true for all $t\in 2\mathbb{Z}$.